# Google AppEngine - Detect If Client Supports HTTP/2

Tags: google-app-engine, http2

I deploy my website to google appengine and I want to take advantage of http/2 (specifically http push) for clients which support it but still serve the bundled version to http/1.x clients.

How can I check the protocol version (using python or even the app.yaml)?

Comment: Check the request header for Upgrade or send a 426 upgrade reqd

Answer (score -2):

Check the request header for Upgrade or send a 426 upgrade reqd

Comment: I don't want to upgrade the connection, I want to check if it's already in HTTP/2. Chrome for example use HTTP/2 by default when possible